# What is the desirable way to go about getting an answer to an old, low-effort question?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

I encounter this problem from time to time.

1. I search the site for a question I want to ask, only to find it has been asked years ago.
2. I find it has been asked as a question-statement question, i.e., the question is there, but there's nothing else.  (Or it suffers from laziness in other ways.)
3. The answers are poor, and I suspect it's because of the low-effort question.

I don't care who asks the question, but I want a good quality answer to it.  Possibilities:

- I could edit it, and include *my motivation* for asking the question, and describe what *I* know about the problem.  This doesn't seem appropriate.
- I could ask my question, and vote to close the low-effort question as a duplicate of the my new question.  This seems impolite and arrogant.
- I could add a bounty to their question, but it feels wrong to benefit someone for a low-effort question.

Or... I could just ask the duplicate question knowingly; see [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

**Question**: What is the desirable way to go about getting an answer to an old, low-effort question?